# Angular $digest() iterations Microsoft WebBrowser Control

Tags: angularjs, webbrowser-control

I have a desktop app built with the Microsoft WebBrowser Control.  Inside the WebBrowser Control, I'm running an Angular app with ng-route.

Everything was working great with Angular 1.2.26. I upgraded to 1.2.27 and now whenever the angular route changes, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations
```

Same error with Angular 1.3.x. I looked at the change log for 1.2.27 and noticed there are some changes with how history is handled. (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1227-prime-factorization-2014-11-20).
If I run the app in a standalone browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE11), no error.  I have tried disabling parts of the app and I still see the error when using the Web Control, so I'm thinking it has to do with the WebBrowser Control.

My question is: Is there a feature that is needed that the web control is restricting?  I have set the registry keys so it will render as IE11 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation). Is there anything else?

Thank you